# How to obtain class instance of generic argument type

Tags: java, generics

In code, if I write a code line like this:

```
GClass<Double> x = new GClass<Double>();
```

And let say, that the class is like this:

```
public static class GClass<T> {
  private T value = null;
  public GClass() {
    // What is T? 
  }
}
```

Where I inserted the question "What is T?", I don't want the value (that is `null`), but its type (that is `Double`).

Comment: in what case would you need to do that? Surely the client that instantiates gClass would be aware of it's parameterised type anyway?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't find out `T` at execution time unless you add a constructor parameter to take `Class<T>` parameter and pass call it with `Double.class` in your case. You can then store that class and use it later.

This is due to *type erasure*... basically generics are just compiler magic to insert appropriate casts and check that things *should* be okay.

See the [Type Erasure](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Type%20Erasure) section of the excellent [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html).

You might also want to read Neal Gafter's blog posts about [super type tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) and [type literals](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/type-literals.html).