# Cannot instantiate generic data type in class

Tags: java, generics

I have an immutable class , with the following layout ,

```
public final class A <T> {
    private ArrayList<T> myList;
    private A(){
        myList = new ArrayList<T>();
    }
    public A<T> addData(T t){
        A newOb = // make a new list and instantiate using overloaded constructor
        T newT = new T(); ***********ERROR HERE*************
        newOb.myList.add(newT);
        return newOb;
    }
    .........
}
```

The error that I get here is `cannot instantiate type T` . Now , I think this is related to maybe `type erasure` in Java.

How can I overcome this ? I want to add a new copy of the argument that is being passed to addData into my list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to obtain class instance generic argument type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372432/how-to-obtain-class-instance-generic-argument-type)

Comment: Objects are created at Runtime. So we need proper byte code at run time. at max Java erasure can do convert `T newT = new T();`  to `Object newT = new Object()` to be available on runtime. But that also wrong since `T` can be anything `extends Object` not only `Object`. Hence compiler error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java language generics are implemented by erasure, so it is impossible to instantiate a generic type. Also it is impossible to instiate an array of generic type and so on.

> How can I overcome this ? I want to add a new copy of the argument
>   that is being passed to addData into my list.

You can try to use `Cloneable` interface as a type bound or add your own similar interface.

Comment: `Cloneable` as type bound is completely useless

Comment: Unless it is used right and `clone()` is implemented, I suppose.

Comment: in order to call a method on an expression, the static type of the expression must have this method

Comment: So `T extends Object & Cloneable` would be more applicable. Nice addition, I did not notice that.

Comment: everything automatically extends `Object`. That doesn't matter. `Object`'s `clone` is not public and is only meant for a subclass to use to call the super implementation. There is no abstract type that specifies a public `clone` method in Java.

Answer (score 8):

```
T newT = (T) t.getClass().newInstance() // assuming zero args constructor and you'll
                                        // have to catch some reflection exceptions
```

Comment: I used this , T was Integer in my class , it threw exceptions at runtime.

Comment: @sTEAK.: so if you could do `new T()`, what would it mean when `T` is `Integer` anyway?

Comment: At complile time T is replaced by Object

Answer (score 5):

In Java 8 you can pass a *factory lambda* which would create a new instance of the desired type:

```
public final class A <T> {
    private ArrayList<T> myList;
    private A(){
        myList = new ArrayList<T>();
    }
    public A<T> addData(Supplier<T> factory){
        A newOb = // make a new list and instantiate using overloaded constructor
        T newT = factory.get();
        newOb.myList.add(newT);
        return newOb;
    }
    .........
}
```

Use it like this for example:

```
A<Integer> a = new A<>();
a.addData( () -> new Integer(0) );
```

The built-in no-argument [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/function/Supplier.html) interface can be used as the wrapper for the callback.

Comment: This should be the way to go, without workarounds and/or assumptions...

Comment: Should be the accepted answer.

I am not pro in Java but I guess explicit type casting is rarely a good sign... What do the pros say ?

Comment: Hello, great solution! I came up with a doubt, hoping you could share some light, why do I need to create a new A just because it is declared as final? Or is it a best practice to create a new class?

Answer (score 1):

I looked for solution of similar problem. Here is the solution I made:

```
public final class ImmutableA<T> {
private ArrayList<T> myList;
private Class<T> clazz;

public static <E> ImmutableA<E> createEmpty(Class<E> clazz) {
    return new ImmutableA<>(clazz);
}

private ImmutableA(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.myList = new ArrayList<T>();
    this.clazz = clazz;
}

public ImmutableA<T> addData(T t) {
    ImmutableA<T> newOb = new ImmutableA<>(clazz);
    try {
        Constructor<T> constructor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(clazz);
        T newT = constructor.newInstance(t);
        newOb.myList.add(newT);
        return newOb;
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public ArrayList<T> getMyList() {
    return myList;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    ImmutableA<String> immutableA = createEmpty(String.class);
    System.out.print(immutableA.getMyList().toString());
    immutableA = immutableA.addData("a");
    System.out.print(immutableA.getMyList().toString());
    immutableA = immutableA.addData("b");
    System.out.print(immutableA.getMyList().toString());
    immutableA = immutableA.addData("c");
    System.out.print(immutableA.getMyList().toString());
}
```

}

Hope this will help to somebody.

Answer (score 0):

You can use clone() method like this:

```
public final class A <T extends Cloneable> {
    private ArrayList<T> myList;
    private A(){
        myList = new ArrayList<T>();
    }
    public A<T> addData(T t){
        T newT = t.clone();
        newOb.myList.add(newT);
        return newOb;
    }
    .........
}
```

Comment: Assume my T is Date , and I do 
`Date d = new Date();
 A a = new A();
 a.addData(d);
 d.setDate(10);
` , then will the value in the List be changed or not ?\

Comment: Yes, you call a setter of a mutable object you added into the list so you change also the value in the list.

Comment: Okay . That was the main purpose behind creating a new copy of the data that was to be inserted. But turns out it doesn't work.

Comment: if you make myList.add(d.clone()) and then call d.setX() this will not change the value into the list

Comment: @jolivier The idea is nice. But I think the clone method won't work on a generic.

Answer (score -1):

you can get the type of T doing

```
Type type = new TypeToken<T>(){}.getType();
```

then get an instance of T doing

```
type.getClass().newInstance();
```

Complete example

```
public T foo() {
    try {
        return (T) type.getClass().newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```